# R crashes with "caught illegal operation" when installing gert

Tags: r, installation, gert

I'm using R 3.4.4 and Ubuntu 16.04 and following gert installation instructions [here](https://github.com/r-lib/gert#installation). I have installed libgit2-dev, but gert installation crashes with the error below:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fbf6f06b405, cause 'illegal operand'

Traceback:
 1: .Call(R_git_config_list, NULL)
 2: git_config_global()
 3: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 4: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 5: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 6: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
 7: try({    settings <- git_config_global()    name <- subset(settings, name == "user.name")$value    email <- subset(settings, name == "user.email")$value    if (length(name) || length(email)) {        packageStartupInform("Default user: %s <%s>", as_string(name),             as_string(email))    }    else {        packageStartupInform("No default user configured")    }})
 8: fun(libname, pkgname)
 9: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
10: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
11: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
12: tryCatch(fun(libname, pkgname), error = identity)
13: runHook(".onAttach", ns, dirname(nspath), nsname)
14: attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)
15: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
16: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
17: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
18: tryCatch({    attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc    ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)}, error = function(e) {    P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e)))         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])    else ""    msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s",         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))    if (logical.return)         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)    else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)})
19: library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)
20: withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
21: suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib,     character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE))
22: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
23: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
24: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
25: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = outFile)        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
26: try(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(pkg_name, lib.loc = lib,     character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE)))
27: tools:::.test_load_package("gert", "/home/viktoriya/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue and this fixed it for me. Try

```
Sys.setenv(USE_SYSTEM_LIBGIT2=1)
install.packages("gert")
```

https://github.com/r-lib/gert/issues/117